# undefined type Auth

Tags: php, laravel

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers; 

use Auth; 
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class maincontroller extends Controller 
{ 
    public function home(Request $request)
    { 
        if(Auth::Attempt($request->only('email','password'))) { 
            return redirect('/'); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Attempt` make it small

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Change the `Auth` namespace from:

```
use Auth;
```

to:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
\Auth::attempt([...]);
```

I think this is helpfull..

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `auth` helper instead and then no worries about any class name

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers; 

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class maincontroller extends Controller 
{ 
    public function home(Request $request)
    { 
        if(auth()->attempt($request->only('email','password'))) { 
            return redirect('/'); 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the **Auth** namespace to:

> use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).